# Footer overlapping body

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my document.  I need to add a footer to the bottom of each printed page only.  I have tried using @media print and creating one main div that contains 2 other divs (content and footer).
I have the following CSS:

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    #wrap {
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    #main {
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
    #myFooter {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    #printFooter {
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: -50px auto 0 auto
    }
}
```

and have the following (abbreviated version) for my body:

```
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="main">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                   <td>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="myFooter">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td id="printFooter"><div>For Official Use Only (FOUO)</div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, I am still getting the footer overlapping the main document when I print.  What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this so that the footer won't overlap?

Chris

Comment: You have a fixed position with margin: -50px on top which might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS [calc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) property,

```
#wrap {
        height: calc( 100% - px);
    }
```

You wouldn't need the main div if you chose this method.
Here is a [DEMO](http://www.cssdesk.com/fx42K)

Comment: I've tried using the calc property, but it doesn't appear to be doing anything with the printed pages.  The footer is still displaying over the contents of the pages.  I've tried changing the min-height of the upper div, but that didn't do it either.